# Create Image from Path Chosen by Touch Events in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create an image from whatever the user has created on screen using the Touch Events. I do not want to store the entire canvas as a bitmap. I want to store only the figure drawn by the user. I want the Path Stored as a bitmap.

Please Help.

```
public class DoodleEngine extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

public DoodleEngine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
float eventX = event.getX();
float eventY = event.getY();

switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

  path.reset();
  invalidate();
  path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
  return true;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
  path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);


  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  // nothing to do
  break;
default:
  return false;
}

// Schedules a repaint.
invalidate();
return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

- Create an instance of Bitmap using [`Bitmap.createBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.util.DisplayMetrics,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) , you may need to work out some dimensions for it.
- Create a canvas instance pointing that this bitmap using `Canvas(Bitmap)` constructor
- Draw **only** your path to the new canvas
- Use the bitmap

Comment: I understand that by doing this I will only get the path on the new canvas and I will get the bitmap of that path but with that Path I will be getting the bitmap of the entire Canvas (Even If it is empty). How do I get the bitmap of that specific Path. I mean that how can I create a Rect from the specific path and can use it

Comment: My Exact Problem is that There will be other things on the screen (Canvas) and whatever User Selects I need to rotate it again and again. But If I rotate the entire Canvas other thing will also rotate which I dont want